# UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) fail for a particular url

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to fetch an url (https://www.leboncoin.fr/recherche?text=rtx%203070&search_in=subject) with app script :
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

It works perfectly fine with other urls but not this one ? It seems like I can't access this particular url ?

Comment: When I tested your URL using `UrlFetchApp.fetch`, I confirmed that the status code `403` is returned. In this case, it is considered that the URL cannot be accessed from Google side. So, in this case, I flagged it as a duplicated question.

Comment: Though I can google it but why can't I access it through code ? There is no solutions for that ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Though I can google it`, I couldn't notice it from your question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. About `but why can't I access it through code ?`, you can see the duplicated questions. About your new question of `There is no solutions for that ?`, in this case, how about using another language instead of Google Apps Script?